# Valid Email Check Error

Tags: python

Can Someone Help me ?

```
login_mail = raw_input("Email >> ")
login_password = raw_input("Password >> ")
print "[+]Wait Check For Valid Email Address."
match = re.search(r"(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9.]*\.*[com|org|edu]{3}$)",login_mail)
while login_mail != match:
    print "error.."
    login_mail = raw_input("Email >> ")
else:
    print "good"
```

When I start the program I put in a valid email example (test@gmail.com) and it prints `error..`

Any Help?

Comment: `if match:`, check the documentation on what `match` in your case actually is.

Comment: I don't think `re.search()` returns a string that would have the same contents as `login_mail`, instead I might recommend having your `while` be `while match:` as if there is no match found than `match` will equal `none` which will mean the `while` loop will not operate

Comment: Also, your regex will report many valid email addresses as invalid.

Comment: can you give me a good regex checker ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `re.search` returns a `MatchObject`. See:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-objects

You can fix this by changing the while loop condition to:

```
while not match:
    print 'error'
    login_mail = raw_input('Email >> ')
    match = re.search(...)
```

You need `not match` in the while loop to check for the search returning `None` (as it does when there is no match). You don't necessarily need to compare the match with `login_mai`l because in the case your match isn't `None`, it will be`login_mail`. There are potentially better regexes to check for valid emails, but what you've got is a reasonable place to start.

If you do want to access the text of your match, you can do something like `match.group(0)`, which will return the first captured group.

You'll still have an issue in that the match object should still be recomputed,though.

Comment: hey that work.. when i put test@gmail.com say good.. but when i put test say error.. and ask me to put email again.. i put and say error .. look http://prntscr.com/fykysf

Comment: i dont understand you :/

Comment: You set `match = re.search...`. You need to do the same thing within the while loop after the user has re-input their email. Otherwise you'll keep checking the same result that failed initially.

Comment: See my edit. All you need to do is update `match` to check the new input. You definitely don't want a nested while loop.